# Algorithm for simplifying a deep tree?

Tags: cart

Suppose that I have a very deep tree, which is not simplified, i.e many terminal nodes can be regrouped. 
Does exist an algorithm for simplifying this complicated tree? (The final tree is not necessery binary).

I think of sorting node by each variable (sort by $x_1$ then by $x_2$, then by $x_3$, ....) then regroup nodes having the same value. But this algorithm is not optimal.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruning_(decision_trees). Note that finding a minimal decision tree is an NP complete problem so you'll find mostly heuristics.

Comment: @danlevin I mean simplying to the exact same tree, not pruning.

Comment: I don't think that it is too practical but there is the classic paper of  Randal E. Bryant, Graph-Based Algorithms for Boolean Function Manipulation (1986) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.5124